# Sqlite3 error: 'no such table' when starting node server with nodemon

Tags: node.js, sqlite, nodemon

**Problem:**

When I start my node.js server using the command `node_modules/.bin/nodemon path/to/server.js` I get an error: `'no such table'` when my code tries to query my sqlite3 database.

**Details:**

- The command: `node_modules/.bin/nodemon path/to/server.js` is the same as `nodemon path/to/server.js`. I use it because I have installed nodemon locally.
- When I run the command: `node path/to/server.js` the application runs as expected.

**Package versions:**

- node: v4.2.6
- sqlite3: ^3.1.8
- nodemon: ^1.11.0

**Code example:**

Below is the function which throws the error when nodemon start the server. I figure that as it works when the server is started by node, this isn't the problem. However, maybe it is important?

```
function selectPassword(callback){
    dataBase = new sqlite3.Database(dataBaseFile, function(error){
        if(error){
            return callback('Error at select password: ' + error);
        }
        //this '.get' method throws the error when the server is                      
        //    started by nodemon.
        dataBase.get('SELECT password FROM users WHERE id = 1', function(error, row){
            if(error){
                console.log('Error at get query: ' + error);
                return callback(error, null);
            }
            //more code
        });
    });
}
```

**Explanation:**

This doesn't really bother me. I was mostly just asking if anyone knew why this happened out of curiosities sake. I want to know what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: The current working directory will be different and you are likely using a relative path someplace (and are ending up with an empty database). Use `path.join(__dirname, ...)` if you are referring to a file that's relative to a source file.

Comment: @cartant that sounds logical. Didn't even think. I'll give it a shot.